# Template or Tool for Comparing Y-DNA Results

Tags: dna, software-recommendations, y-dna

I am looking for a tool, preferably an excel template, I can run on my computer that I can use for comparing Y-DNA results across multiple types of Y-DNA tests.

I realize some version of this exists on the testing sites themselves, but they all have their issues, independent of all of the results not being on the same site.

What I am looking for and hoping someone has found is the ability to compare two rows (test kit results) and determine the maximum number of matches based on the minimum sized kit of the two.

I know how to do a comparison between two cells in excel and get back a positive or negative result which could be used to compare two static rows and then add those up, but that is not the most elegant way of doing things if the row comparison are always changing. So wondering if there is something else out there I just haven't come across yet.

Some examples:

- Test Kit A (Y-37) Test Kit B (Y-111) would only compare the Y-37
  markers present in both kits and provide a differences or a match
  count in a cell up to a maximum of 37.
- Test Kit A (Y-111) Test Kit B
  (Y-12) would only compare the Y-12 markers present in both kits and
  provide a differences or a match count in a cell up to a maximum of

  12. 
- Test Kit A (Y-67) Test Kit B (Y-111) would only compare the Y-67 markers present in both kits and provide a differences or a match
  count in a cell up to a maximum of 67.
- Test Kit A (Y-111) Test Kit B
  (Y-111) would only compare the Y-111 markers present in both kits and
  provide a differences or a match count in a cell up to a maximum of
  111.

Comment: Could you elaborate on some of the issues you have with the existing resources you've tried? The problem is it is not always a simple case of a positive or negative match. That is why there are websites and software to help with the analysis. Different companies use different markers and methods thus may not be easily (or appropriately) comparable in a simple Excel spreadsheet.

Comment: @Vervet Primary issue is they are not all on the same site, secondary issue is the sites do not tell give you stats like 80/111 beyond their match criteria  for displaying, tertiary I do not have permission to upload them all to YSearch. I had all of this and more in the original post but I found it became distracting and could lead to philosophical discussion vs. a specific discussion q&a. And per your point as it is not as simple as positive and negative match it is part of the reason I am asking the question, Im looking for that software or template.

Answer (score 5):

There are a number of free downloadable Y-DNA Tools available at [Genetic Genealogy Tools](http://www.y-str.org/p/tools-utilities.html) by Felix Immanuel, including:

- Y-STR Kit
- Y-Tree Creator
- ISOGG Y-Tree AddOn for Google Chrome
- 23andMe To YSNPs
- YSNP Novel Variants
- Merge Y
- Y-HaploGroup Population Browser
- Y-Haplogroup Predictor

I have not personally tried any of these, but maybe one or more of them will help you.

If not, then given the variety of the various DNA tools the author has there, I would expect he would be open to you suggesting that he write a program to compare the Y markers of two cells.